# Django return list of objects and list of ids from the same queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering if it's possible to select different values from the same queryset. I have a queryset as follows

```
links = Model.objects.filter(some_filters)
ect. 
return links.values('parent_id', 'child_id', 'type', 'date')
```

What I'd like to do is return both the list above, but also a distinct list of child_ids without having to create a new query. For example if the above returns:

```
[(1, 2, 'child', 'some_date'), (2, 3, 'child', 'some_date')]
```

I'd like it instead to return

```
[2, 3], [(1, 2, 'child', 'some_date'), (2, 3, 'child', 'some_date')]
```

Is this possible without creating a new queryset?

Comment: Don't you want `[1, 2, 3, 4]`? Why just values from the second?

Comment: The same model has fields like `parent_id` and `child_id`? Feels like non-normalized database schema to me.

Comment: This table is a many-to-many relationship showing the links between items in another table. service_item_links has a parent_id and a child_id from service_items if that makes sense. I'd like to just find the distinct list of child_ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After assigning the first queryset to a variable, you can get different querysets from it without hitting the db:

```
links = Model.objects.filter(some_filters)
q1 = links.values_list('child_id')
q2 = links.values_list('parent_id', 'child_id', 'type', 'date')
return q1, q2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your results to extract only those child IDs and check in each iteration if that id is already in there

```
child_ids = []
for record in results:
    if (record[1] not in child_ids):
        child_ids.append(record[1])
```